# Adding substr() to <?php the_title();?>

Tags: php, wordpress

I've found a few tutorials on adding substr() to variables but not to functions. The output in html so far is:

```
<div class="symbol"><?php the_title();?></h3>
```

Inside `the_title()` when I hover over it the following function in Eclipse it displays:

```
function = the_title($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true){
    $title = get_the_title();

    if (strlen($title) == 0 )
        return
    $title = $before . $title . $after

    if ($echo)
        echo $title;

    else
        ...
```

I'm just unsure whether I need to add to the function in the backend pages or I can code it in the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `get_the_title()` in wordpress to get the current title returned as a string:

```
$title = get_the_title();
$title_substr = substr($title, -1);
```

You don't have to store the title in a variable, you can just go straight to:

```
$substr = substr(get_the_title(), -1);
```

Comment: Getting the php to find the nearest completed word with 12 characters limited (code above)